# Processing: Is there a way to put my shapes into a loop and make my code shorter?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, object, svg, processing

I am making an loyalty card and with every mouseclick one part of an svg image gets stamped with disableStyle().

I cannot seem to find a way in where I can make PShapes in a loop and disable their style with getChild().

I only get it to work in this way. I know it can be shorter with some solution. But how?

```
import processing.svg.*;
import java.util.ArrayList; 

PImage bg;
PImage bg2;
PShape bolsvg;
//PShape bol1,bol2,bol3,bol4,bol5, bol6,bol7,bol8,bol9, bol10,bol11,bol12,bol13;
PShape[] bollen = new PShape[80];
int kwartje = 0;
//ArrayList shapes = new ArrayList();


void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  bg = loadImage("bg1.png");
  bg2 = loadImage("bg2.png");
  bolsvg = loadShape("Bolletjes.svg");

  PShape bol1 = bolsvg.getChild("1");
  PShape bol2 = bolsvg.getChild("2");
  PShape bol3 = bolsvg.getChild("3");
  PShape bol4 = bolsvg.getChild("4");
  PShape bol5 = bolsvg.getChild("5");
  PShape bol6 = bolsvg.getChild("6");
  PShape bol7 = bolsvg.getChild("7");
  PShape bol8 = bolsvg.getChild("8");
  PShape bol9 = bolsvg.getChild("9");
  PShape bol10 = bolsvg.getChild("10");

  PShape bol11 = bolsvg.getChild("11");
  PShape bol12 = bolsvg.getChild("12");
  PShape bol13 = bolsvg.getChild("13");
  PShape bol14 = bolsvg.getChild("14");
  PShape bol15 = bolsvg.getChild("15");
  PShape bol16 = bolsvg.getChild("16");
  PShape bol17 = bolsvg.getChild("17");
  PShape bol18 = bolsvg.getChild("18");
  PShape bol19 = bolsvg.getChild("19");
  PShape bol20 = bolsvg.getChild("20");

  PShape bol21 = bolsvg.getChild("21");
  PShape bol22 = bolsvg.getChild("22");
  PShape bol23 = bolsvg.getChild("23");
  PShape bol24 = bolsvg.getChild("24");
  PShape bol25 = bolsvg.getChild("25");
  PShape bol26 = bolsvg.getChild("26");
  PShape bol27 = bolsvg.getChild("27");
  PShape bol28 = bolsvg.getChild("28");
  PShape bol29 = bolsvg.getChild("29");
  PShape bol30 = bolsvg.getChild("30");

  PShape bol31 = bolsvg.getChild("31");
  PShape bol32 = bolsvg.getChild("32");
  PShape bol33 = bolsvg.getChild("33");
  PShape bol34 = bolsvg.getChild("34");
  PShape bol35 = bolsvg.getChild("35");
  PShape bol36 = bolsvg.getChild("36");
  PShape bol37 = bolsvg.getChild("37");
  PShape bol38 = bolsvg.getChild("38");
  PShape bol39 = bolsvg.getChild("39");
  PShape bol40 = bolsvg.getChild("40");

  PShape bol41 = bolsvg.getChild("41");
  PShape bol42 = bolsvg.getChild("42");
  PShape bol43 = bolsvg.getChild("43");
  PShape bol44 = bolsvg.getChild("44");
  PShape bol45 = bolsvg.getChild("45");
  PShape bol46 = bolsvg.getChild("46");
  PShape bol47 = bolsvg.getChild("47");
  PShape bol48 = bolsvg.getChild("48");
  PShape bol49 = bolsvg.getChild("49");
  PShape bol50 = bolsvg.getChild("50");

  PShape bol51 = bolsvg.getChild("51");
  PShape bol52 = bolsvg.getChild("52");
  PShape bol53 = bolsvg.getChild("53");
  PShape bol54 = bolsvg.getChild("54");
  PShape bol55 = bolsvg.getChild("55");
  PShape bol56 = bolsvg.getChild("56");
  PShape bol57 = bolsvg.getChild("57");
  PShape bol58 = bolsvg.getChild("58");
  PShape bol59 = bolsvg.getChild("59");
  PShape bol60 = bolsvg.getChild("60");

  PShape bol61 = bolsvg.getChild("61");
  PShape bol62 = bolsvg.getChild("62");
  PShape bol63 = bolsvg.getChild("63");
  PShape bol64 = bolsvg.getChild("64");
  PShape bol65 = bolsvg.getChild("65");
  PShape bol66 = bolsvg.getChild("66");
  PShape bol67 = bolsvg.getChild("67");
  PShape bol68 = bolsvg.getChild("68");
  PShape bol69 = bolsvg.getChild("69");
  PShape bol70 = bolsvg.getChild("70");

  PShape bol71 = bolsvg.getChild("71");
  PShape bol72 = bolsvg.getChild("72");
  PShape bol73 = bolsvg.getChild("73");
  PShape bol74 = bolsvg.getChild("74");
  PShape bol75 = bolsvg.getChild("75");
  PShape bol76 = bolsvg.getChild("76");
  PShape bol77 = bolsvg.getChild("77");
  PShape bol78 = bolsvg.getChild("78");
  PShape bol79 = bolsvg.getChild("79");
  PShape bol80 = bolsvg.getChild("80");

  //for(int i =0; i<20;i++){
  //  bol1 = bolsvg.getChild(i);

  //}
  bollen[0] = bol1;
  bollen[1] = bol2;
  bollen[2] = bol3;
  bollen[3] = bol4;
  bollen[4] = bol5;
  bollen[5] = bol6;
  bollen[6] = bol7;
  bollen[7] = bol8;
  bollen[8] = bol9;
  bollen[9] = bol10;

  bollen[10] = bol11;
  bollen[11] = bol12;
  bollen[12] = bol13;
  bollen[13] = bol14;
  bollen[14] = bol15;
  bollen[15] = bol16;
  bollen[16] = bol17;
  bollen[17] = bol18;
  bollen[18] = bol19;
  bollen[19] = bol20;

  bollen[20] = bol21;
  bollen[21] = bol22;
  bollen[22] = bol23;
  bollen[23] = bol24;
  bollen[24] = bol25;
  bollen[25] = bol26;
  bollen[26] = bol27;
  bollen[27] = bol28;
  bollen[28] = bol29;
  bollen[29] = bol30;

  bollen[30] = bol31;
  bollen[31] = bol32;
  bollen[32] = bol33;
  bollen[33] = bol34;
  bollen[34] = bol35;
  bollen[35] = bol36;
  bollen[36] = bol37;
  bollen[37] = bol38;
  bollen[38] = bol39;
  bollen[39] = bol40;

  bollen[40] = bol41;
  bollen[41] = bol42;
  bollen[42] = bol43;
  bollen[43] = bol44;
  bollen[44] = bol45;
  bollen[45] = bol46;
  bollen[46] = bol47;
  bollen[47] = bol48;
  bollen[48] = bol49;
  bollen[49] = bol50;
  bollen[50] = bol51;

  bollen[51] = bol52;
  bollen[52] = bol53;
  bollen[53] = bol54;
  bollen[54] = bol55;
  bollen[55] = bol56;
  bollen[56] = bol57;
  bollen[57] = bol58;
  bollen[58] = bol59;
  bollen[59] = bol60;
  bollen[60] = bol61;

  bollen[61] = bol62;
  bollen[62] = bol63;
  bollen[63] = bol64;
  bollen[64] = bol65;
  bollen[65] = bol66;
  bollen[66] = bol67;
  bollen[67] = bol68;
  bollen[68] = bol69;
  bollen[69] = bol70;
  bollen[70] = bol71;

  bollen[71] = bol72;
  bollen[72] = bol73;
  bollen[73] = bol74;
  bollen[74] = bol75;
  bollen[75] = bol76;
  bollen[76] = bol77;
  bollen[77] = bol78;
  bollen[78] = bol79;
  bollen[79] = bol80;


  //  for(int i = 1; i< 80; i++){
  //    shapes.add(bollen[i]);
  //  }
  //}
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  image(bg, 0, 0);
  shape(bolsvg, 0, -122);
  image(bg2, 30, 82);
  //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // bollen[i] = kwart.getChild(i);
  //}
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    }
    kwartje++;
    if (kwartje > 79) {
      kwartje = 79;
    }
    bollen[kwartje].disableStyle();
    print(kwartje);
    
  } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    if (kwartje < 0) {
      kwartje = 0;
    }
    bollen[kwartje].enableStyle();
    kwartje--;
    print(kwartje);
    
  } else {
    fill(251, 210, 114);
  }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) bollen[i] = bolsvg.getChild(Integer.toString(i+1));`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp you should post the comment as an answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Johny Mopp's answer, it's worth considering if bolsvg's children are just the layers from "1" to "80".

If so, after you load the SVG you can simply use `PShape`'s [`getChildren()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PShape.html#getChildren--):

```java
bollen = bolsvg.getChildren();
```

In fact, since it only appears you need this array along with an index, you can just use [`getChild(index)`](https://processing.org/reference/PShape_getChild_.html):

```java
PImage bg;
PImage bg2;
PShape bolsvg;
int kwartje = 0;


void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  bg = loadImage("bg1.png");
  bg2 = loadImage("bg2.png");
  bolsvg = loadShape("Bolletjes.svg");
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  image(bg, 0, 0);
  shape(bolsvg, 0, -122);
  image(bg2, 30, 82);
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    kwartje++;
    if (kwartje > 79) {
      kwartje = 79;
    }
    bolsvg.getChild(kwartje).disableStyle();
    print(kwartje);
    
  } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    kwartje--;
    if (kwartje < 0) {
      kwartje = 0;
    }
    bolsvg.getChild(kwartje).enableStyle();
    print(kwartje);
    
  } else {
    fill(251, 210, 114);
  }
  
}
```

or, if there multiple layers and the naming is crucial:

```java
PImage bg;
PImage bg2;
PShape bolsvg;
int kwartje = 0;


void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  bg = loadImage("bg1.png");
  bg2 = loadImage("bg2.png");
  bolsvg = loadShape("Bolletjes.svg");
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  image(bg, 0, 0);
  shape(bolsvg, 0, -122);
  image(bg2, 30, 82);
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    kwartje++;
    if (kwartje > 79) {
      kwartje = 79;
    }
    bolsvg.getChild(""+(kwartje+1)).disableStyle();
    print(kwartje);
    
  } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    kwartje--;
    if (kwartje < 0) {
      kwartje = 0;
    }
    bolsvg.getChild(""+(kwartje+1)).enableStyle();
    print(kwartje);
    
  } else {
    fill(251, 210, 114);
  }
  
}
```

The `kwartje` index + 1 gets to the range 1 to 80 and concatenating the `int` with a String("") is another of converting that `int` to a string. (`Integer.toString(kwartje + 1)` would've had the same effect)

Note the above code isn't tested so might crash on an error,
but hopefully it does illustrate the idea.